# Set model property in jQuery

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to set Model property **Id** as follows :

```
'<%= Model.Id %>' = $("#Id");
```

But getting error in Firebug :

```
Invalid left-hand side in assignment.
```

How to set `Model.Id`?

Comment: if you want to set model.id from view is not possible. Javascript executed on client side, but model.id on server

Comment: And even if it was possible: you have to use `$("#Id").val()`, otherwise you are trying to assign a jQuery object as value.

Comment: Not sure why you need to set the value to the property of model. if you are looking for during postback, Just have a input control or hidden control as ID. while the page postback, modelbinder able to get it for you in ur controller.

Comment: @kjana83 : Already done what you are saying. Still not getting value in Id.

Comment: how you are getting in the controllor, through formcollection or modelbinding. check if the id is within in the Form tag in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you write in this way

`'<%= Model.Id %>' = $("#Id");`

so it is not possible to set any var to `'56'` (For example let be 56), so you try set value to number...